# what is difference between [Classname]() and Classname() in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, initialization

I want to know difference between

```
    var arr = ExamCategory() 
             &
    var arrExamCategories = [ExamCategory]()
```

Please Why this is declared like this and which should be use for better?

My `ExamCategory` class is like this.

```
class ExamCategory: NSObject {

    var CategoryId: Int?
    var CategoryName:String?
    var TotalSection: Int?
    var ImageUrl: String?

    override init() {

    }

    init(dict:[String:Any]) {
        super.init()

        CategoryId = dict["categoryId"] as? Int
        CategoryName = dict["categoryName"] as? String
        TotalSection = dict["totalSection"] as? Int
       ImageUrl = dict[""] as? String
    }
  .....And So On
}
```

Can anyone describe and differentiate both in details?

Comment: "arr" is a single object kind of class "ExamCategory" and "arrExamCategories" is array of object of class "ExamCategory".

Comment: ok, But we can store array into single object kind of class "ExamCategory" So why should we declare like second one? @YagneshDobariya and which is better one?

Comment: you can, but its still a single object contains array, the other one is array contains single objects, its different

Comment: @Tj3n which is better to use? You say that the other one is used array of elements while the first one single element.

Comment: @Jitendra Modi. It is up to you. If you need a single object to manage then first one is better. And suppose you need to manage multiple object of same kind of class then second one is better. While you use second one for single object then you need to fetch object from array index each and every time while you want to perform some operation on it.

Answer (score 2):

Both have different usage, they cannot be compared with each other. When you need to store multiple elements, you should use array but if you need single element you should choose single default initiazer. It depends upon your need. Both are best according to their usage in swift programming.

`ExamCategory()` is a default initializer for your class which invokes`init()` for your class when called using classname with round backets () and returns you an instance of your class.

In your example `ExamCategory()` invokes initializer for class `ExamCategory` and return you a single instance of the class, which your have stored in`var arr`

```
var arr = ExamCategory()
```

while...
`[ExamCategory]()` is an array initializer of type `ExamCategory`. It (can/must) holds/stores an instance of class `ExamCategory` or its sub classes.

In your example, `[ExamCategory]()` is an array for elements of `ExamCategory`. You can insert/add, above `var arr` in this array.

```
var arrExamCategories = [ExamCategory]()
arrExamCategories.append(arr)
```

Here is apple document for [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) and [array (Collection Types)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ExamCategory()
```

It means that: ExamCategory class has been initialized and reference of this class has been stored in arr variable.

```
var arrExamCategories = [ExamCategory]()
```

It means that: You have initialize an array which contains objects of ExamCategory class.

```
ex: arrExamCategories.append(arr) // var arr = ExamCategory()
```

For more details please refer apple's swift documentation.

Comment: @JitendraModi both are very different and not comparable.

Comment: To create an array of ExamCategory class,var arrExamCategories = [ExamCategory]() will use. And to store the object in array, first you need to create an object of ExamCategory class using var arr = ExamCategory(). And make sure that both are different things.

Comment: ok, I know both are different but here is a case like [ExamCategory]() is storing only array means it is a variable of fix type. We can store only array into this. but now in ExamCategory() , you can store anything because it's type is not fixed, single object. Store anything you want. So, let me know what you think on this? @Krunal

Comment: @JitendraModi I think, you should go through Apple document/tutorial to understand more detail and difference between both.

Comment: Jitendra pleas first go through the Apple's document/tutorial. Than you will understand the whole concept.

Comment: @JitendraModi  for your statement `but now in ExamCategory(), you can store anything because it's type is not fixed` : You cannot store anything in  ExamCategory. You can store it own instance or subclass instance only. Mehul is right.

Comment: arr is an object and arrExamCategories is an array whos type contains ExamCategory objects. It doesn't get more simple than this explanation.